# need help submiting this form with jquery... It is submiting but the whole browser is refreshing

Tags: jquery

```
 $idc = $_GET['id'];
    $name1 = $_GET['name'];
    $id2 = $_GET['ids'];
     if ($_POST['message_field'] != ""){
        $message_field = $_POST['message_field'];

          $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO comment (mem_id,commented_men_id, message, message_date) 
         VALUES('$userid','$idc','$message_field', now())")  
         or die (mysql_error());

    }

        $sql_message = mysql_query("SELECT id, mem_id ,message, message_date FROM comment WHERE mem_id='$userid'  ORDER BY message_date DESC");

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_message)){


            $id = $row["id"];
            $me_id = $row["mem_id"];
            $json = $row["message"];
                 $message_date = $row["message_date"];
                $message = json_encode($json);

 $sql_mem_data = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM users WHERE  id='$me_id'");
              while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql_mem_data)){
                $id = $row2["id"];
                $ufirstname = $row2["name"];
        }

    $messageList .= '<div id="only"><p>' . ufirstname . '</p><br/><p    id="pmessage">'.$the_message.'</p></div>';

    }

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title> Book</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.form.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="mootools-core-1.3.2-full-compat.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

       $("#messageinput").click(function() {
           $.post($('#message').attr("action"),
                  $("#message").serialize(),
                  function(html) {
                    var comment = $(html) .find('#messageoutput').html();
                      $("#pmessage").html(comment);
              });
   });
       });

    </script>
         <div id="messageid">
             <form align="left" id="message" action="<?php profile.php?id='.$idc.'& ids='.    $id2.'&name='.$name1.'?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="blab_from">
        <textarea name="message_field" rows="3" style="width:97%;"></textarea>
         <input id="messageinput" name="submit" type="button" value="submit" align="left" />
        </form>
        </div>
        <div id="messageoutput"><?php print "$messageList"; ?></div>
```

Comment: not at all it will submit normally but refreshing the browser, I just want to submit the comment without refreshing do you have any input or script that does that ?

Comment: Ever seen this using form plugin? - `Error: Form elements must not have name or id of "submit".`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this... Suppose this is your html

```
<form align="left" id="form1" action="" method="post"   enctype="multipart/form-data" name="message_from">
<textarea id="message_field" name="message_field" rows="3" style="width:97%;"></textarea>
<input id="messageinput" name="submit" type="button" value="Submit" align="left" />
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Then the following code will submit the form data and will echo the result back in the 'data' variable.  You can do whatever you want to do with the return data then.  Like in the example i am putting the returned data in a div with id="result".

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#messageinput").click(function(){
        $.post('html.php',$("#form1").serialize(),function(data){
            $("#result").html(data);
        });

    });
});
```

**Solution to your modified script**

```
<?php
//engine.php
//for convinence sake split the php and html into 2 files say php is in engine.php and html in profile.php
//why are you using &name and &ids for? my best guess is u need only &id and &message_field if its a msg post

//this file will do 2 things when id is passed return the comments and when id and message is passed insert the comment into db fetch it again and pass it.
//the html manipulation will be done by jQuery/javascript only you dont need php for that

//  $idc = $_GET['id'];
//  $name1 = $_GET['name'];
//  $id2 = $_GET['ids'];

    $idc = $_POST['id'];//[we are using post so use _POST methods]


    if ($_POST['message_field'] != "")
    {
        //here you are missing connection statements like mysql_connect() and mysql_select_db()
        $message_field = $_POST['message_field'];
        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO comment (mem_id,commented_men_id, message, message_date)VALUES('$userid','$idc','$message_field', now())") or die (mysql_error());  
    }

    $sql_message = mysql_query("SELECT id, mem_id ,message, message_date FROM comment WHERE mem_id='$userid'  ORDER BY message_date DESC");

    $i = 0;
    $messageList = '<div id="result">';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_message))
    {
        $j=$i++;
        $id = $row["id"];
        $me_id = $row["mem_id"];        
        $message_date = $row["message_date"];
        //$json = $row["message"];
        //$message = json_encode($json);
        $message = $row["message"]; //disabling json for now

        $sql_mem_data = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM users WHERE  id='$me_id'");

        while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql_mem_data))
        {
            $id = $row2["id"];
            $ufirstname = $row2["name"];
        }
        //$messageList .= '<div id="only"><p>' . ufirstname . '</p><br/><p    id="pmessage">'.$the_message.'</p></div>'; //[error 1] ur writting this outside while loop also id="only" multiple times will create error same with id="pmessage"
        /*[error 1] rectification*/ $messageList .= '<div id="row_'.$j.'"><p id="uname_'.$j.'">'.$ufirstname.'</p><br/><p id="msg_'.$j.'">'.$message.'</p></div>';
    }
    $messageList .= '</div>'; //making id="result" parent of all the rows
    echo $messageList; //script has to echo for jQuery to catch it.
?>
<!--This file is profile.php(assumption)-->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title> Book</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mootools-core-1.3.2-full-compat.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
/*i still didn't get why you use $id2 and &name2 but the above php block is used to only fetch data which is passed by the javascript
so you need 2 events first when the page is loaded and 2nd when the page is posted with a new comment
*/
(function($)
{
    $.getParam = function(key)
    {
        var urlParams = decodeURI( window.location.search.substring(1) );
        if(urlParams == false | urlParams == '') return null;
        var pairs = urlParams.split("&");

        var keyValue_Collection = {};
        for(var value in pairs)
        {
            var equalsignPosition = pairs[value].indexOf("=");
            if (equalsignPosition == -1) 
                keyValue_Collection[ pairs[value] ] = ''; 
            else
                keyValue_Collection[ pairs[value].substring(0, equalsignPosition) ] = pairs[value].substr(equalsignPosition + 1);
        }
        return keyValue_Collection[key];
    }
})
(jQuery);

//fetch the id to get the messages
var id = $.getParam("id");

//if its a click
$("#messageinput").live('click',function(){
    var msg = $("#message_field").val();
    var qstring='id='+id+'&message_field='+ msg;
    $.post('engine.php',qstring,function(data){
        $("#messageoutput").html(data);//bind the whole data to messageoutput div as its already formatted for right html
    });
});

//else load default messages
var qstring = 'id='+id;
$.post('engine.php',qstring,function(){
    $("#messageoutput").html(data);//in this php script will return only the messages for the passed id.
});

});
</script>
<div id="messageid">
    <form align="left" id="message" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="blab_from">
    <textarea id="message_field" name="message_field" rows="3" style="width:97%;"></textarea>
    <input id="messageinput" name="submit" type="button" value="submit" align="left" />
    </form>
</div>
<!--<div id="messageoutput"><?php/* print "$messageList"; */?></div>--> <!--This is not needed when u do it by AJAX simply put an empty div for results-->
<div id="messageoutput"></div>
```

Comment: this is working but in the action I have some php global variables which I am using and now I don't know how to put it in the post? I put only html.php will return the whole page inside the message lol, I need html.php?id='.$idc.'&ids='. $id2.'&name='.$name1.' can  i put this string inside jquery? and it will call it?

Comment: You can filter the returning data by the following code
    var mydata = $(data).filter('#requireddata');
where 'requireddata' is the selector returning u the data.  And suppose you want to put the data returned in the result then
    $("#result").html(mydata);

Comment: if you want to put additional data then the $.post goes like this

    $.post('html.php','id='.$idc.'&ids='. $id2.'&name='.$name1.',function(data){//other code}

in short the second argument builds what u send by the query string.
**dont put the page name in the 2nd argument and variables in 1st argument**

Comment: I haven't found a solutions yet lonewolf, somehow the variables are not passing and the form is not submiting the comments in the table.

Comment: @fello can you show me your code?  I dont see any complications here you must be doing something wrong.

Comment: @fello There were many mistakes in your code + some misconcepts using AJAX try to follow the changes you'll see what i mean. Putting code in 2 files is better so i've splitted code into 2 files one which has php(engine.php) and other which has html(i assume profile.php).  Doing so will not output the whole page as you observed previously.

Comment: Great Work Lone I have a question in the first post if look at the action of the form there are three variables '.$idc.'& ids='.    $id2.'&name='.$name1.' I need to pass those three variables to activated other parts of the script. They are being passed through the url from page to page. That's why I was using $_GET they are coming from the url no t from the form. what's your take on those variables and how can I pass them on.

Comment: @fello i somehow guessed that so made a $.getParam() function, when you can get the variable coming on the page by this function -> pass it on to engine.php via javascript & display the result via javascript.  PHP does very less here.

var idc = $.getParam('idc'); and it will get you the variable.

Actually as you saw here the engine.php and html files are completly different even if u want to pass var using get or post everything will happen in the background so you dont need to pass variables in url, its completly transparent to the user. Still document.URL='profile.php?id=123&name=xyz'helps

Comment: Hey Lone i have this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/WRAmB/8/ I tried your code but I coudln't get it to work, if you see in this form it is toggling and with the js is submiting but the second form id="bring" I am having trouble to let the code knows what comment is being commented. how can I id each comment and let code knows what member comment I god that but which comment was commented that's where I am lost.

Comment: @fello you're building nested commenting here. I suggest you first get your ajax with single comment working before attempting something like that.  Also the question here has deviated from the topic much so it can be closed or something.  If you need more help i'd be glad to help you out if you try contacting me on lonewolfs.glory@gmail.com

Comment: @fello also what you are trying to do at fiddle might require database structuring

Comment: I think the submission of the parent comment is handled, I need the nested comment handling now. it figuring out a way to id each comment iteration and then using that unique id to guide the nested comment to display and insert in the right parent comment

Comment: LoneWolf I have an edit part in here at this thread similar to this situation where the topic has changed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129328/want-to-know-whether-this-is-a-html-php-or-javascript-issue

Answer (score 1):

Use `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"` in input tag.
Because submit button will submit the form and refresh the page.

Comment: with the existing jquery code above and changed to type="button" the form won't insert at all now. What could that be?

Comment: i don't see start script tag which should be located above `$(document).ready`. typo error?

Comment: hey karthi I do have it in the original document excuse me for the typo.

Comment: hey karthi it might be inserting but it is not returning to the site like ajax type where it will refresh only the comment. without having to r efresh the whole site

Comment: @fello, change form id to form1 or any except 'form' and try with submit/button input type.

Comment: Nothing! I don't see any new comments in the database.

Comment: Move `$('#form').ajaxForm` function to end of form. because this fn will help to bind the form after it has been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

i think you cannot submit a form with out refreshing the page using  type="submit". instead use `type="submit"` use `type="button"`

Comment: with the existing jquery code above and changed to type="button" the form won't insert at all now. What could that be?

Comment: yep , you have to send a request using $.post or $.ajax in your    $('.button').click function  . it is different than submit

Comment: Is you change the submit to a button then any people with JavaScript disabled won't get your form functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) event on the form rather than click.

```
$('#submit).submit(function() {
  alert('Handler for .submit() called.');
  return false;
});
```