# want to know whether this is a html, php or javascript issue

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want to id each comment so that where any member comment on a comment, the INSERT and the SELECT knows where to display the comments, who commented in a comment and in what comment. it is like creating an id for each comment so the SELECT display each message in its place. bu i don't know if it is an html, php or javascript issue to handle.  the jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WRAmB/8).

php

I do pick the id in the url string

```
 $id = $_GET['id']; // this id of the user being commented in the user table I guess I will need that id to identify which user is being commented "profile" that's the id of his profile
 if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {    
 $userid = $_SESSION['id']; 
 $username = $_SESSION['name']; }
  else {

   // do this

  }
 // the userid contains the id and name of the user commenting "the user logged in".

 if ($_POST['comment_field_1'] != ""){



     $comment_field_1 = $_POST['comment_field_1'];
 $comment_field_1 = stripslashes($comment_field_1);
 $comment_field_1 = strip_tags($comment_field_1);
 $comment_field_1 = mysql_real_escape_string($comment_field_1);
 $comment_field_1 = eregi_replace("'", "&#39;", $comment_field_1);

 $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments (mem_id,commented_men_id, the_message,parent_id, message_date) 
 VALUES('$userid','$idc','$comment_field_1', $parent_id now())")  
 or die (mysql_error());

    // i guess the $parent_id should be initialize somewhere in the top with a value of 0 or 1 depending weather it is a response or a comment.
}

     // men_id is the field of the $userid, commented_men_id is the field for the commented on, $idc variable etc...

if ($_POST['comment_field_2'] != ""){  // responses form field



     $comment_field_2 = $_POST['comment_field_2'];
 $comment_field_2 = stripslashes($comment_field_2);
 $comment_field_2 = strip_tags($comment_field_2);
 $comment_field_2 = mysql_real_escape_string($comment_field_2);
 $comment_field_2 = eregi_replace("'", "&#39;", $comment_field_2);

 $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments (mem_id,commented_men_id, the_message,sub_commented_id, message_date) 
 VALUES('$userid','$idc','$comment_field_1', $sub_commented_id now())")  
 or die (mysql_error());

    // here instead of $parent_id I use field created for responses to tag a comment as a response should be initialize somewhere in the top with a value of 0 or 1 depending weather it is a response or a comment. I am not sure weather I should leave the parent_id variable or come with this new field $sub_commented_id. What do you think?
}

     // men_id is the field of the $userid, commented_men_id is the field for the commented on, $idc variable etc...


if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {

if ($_SESSION['id'] == $userid ) {
 $the_message_form = ' 


comment (220 char max)
<form align="left" id="comment" action="profile.php?id='.$idc.'" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="message_from">
<textarea type="text" id="text1" name="comment_field_1" rows="3" style="width:97%;"></textarea>

 <input class="commentinput" name="submit" type="button"  value="submit comment" align="left" />

</form>';

    }
} 

$sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT id, mem_id, commented_men_id, the_message,parent_id, message_date FROM comments WHERE commented_men_id='$idc' ORDER BY message_date DESC LIMIT 20")or die ( mysql_error () );
 $i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql1)){
    $j = $i++;
    $message_id = $row["id"];
    $uid = $row["mem_id"];
    $the_message= $row["the_message"];
    $message_date = $row["message_date"];
    $message_date = strftime("%b %d, %Y, %Y %I:%M:%S %p", strtotime($message_date));


    $sql_mem_data = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM users WHERE id='$uid' LIMIT 1");
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql_mem_data)){
            $uid = $row2["id"];
            $ufirstname = $row2["name"];
            $ufirstname =  mb_strimwidth($ufirstname, 0, 20, '&hellip;');


    }

            $messageDisplayList .= '
                <table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="4" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" style="margin-bottom:0.5em">
        <tr>
          <td width="auto" height="auto" bgcolor="#EFEFEF" style="vertical-align:top"><a width="auto" height="auto" title="'.$row2["name"] .' "href="profile.php?id='.$uid .'&name='.$row2["name"].'">' .$user_pic. '</a><br />
          </td>
          <td width="93%" bgcolor="#EFEFEF"><a href="profile.php?id='.$uid.'">' . $ufirstname . ' </a> &bull; <span style="font-size:10px; font-weight:bold; color:#A6A6A6;">' . $message_date . '</span><br />
  <p id="only">    ' . $the_message . '</p><span class="comment">&bull;<a style="padding-left:3.5px; color:#0099ff" href ="">Comment</a></span><div class="commentForm"><form align="left" id="bring" action="profile.php?id='. $uid .'" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="message_from">
<textarea name="comment_field_2" type="text" id="text2" rows="3" style="width:100%; height:30px;"></textarea>
 <input id="bringinput" name="submit" type="button" value="submit" align="left" />
</form></div>
 </td>
  </tr>
      </table> <br/>';
      }
      $sql_sub_coment = mysql_query ("SELECT id, mem_id, commented_men_id, sub_commented_id, the_message, message_date FROM comments WHERE sub_commented_id='$blabid3' AND sub_commented_id != 0 ORDER BY blab_date DESC LIMIT 20");
    while($row3= mysql_fetch_array($sql_sub_coment)){
    $$message_id3 = $row3_sub["id"];
    $uid3 = $row3_sub["mem_id"] ;
    $the_message3 = $row3_sub["the_message"];
    $message_date3 = $row3_sub["message_date"];
    $message_date3 = strftime("%b %d, %Y, %Y %I:%M:%S %p", strtotime($blab_date3));
    $sql_mem_data = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM user WHERE id='$uid3' LIMIT 1");
        while($row4 = mysql_fetch_array($sql_mem_data)){
            $uid4 = $row4["category_id"];
            $ufirstname2 = $row4["name"];
            $ufirstname2 =  mb_strimwidth($ufirstname2, 0, 20, '&hellip;');

}
            $$messageDisplayList2 .= '<table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="4" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" style="margin-bottom:0.5em">
        <tr>
          <td width="auto" height="auto" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><a width="auto" height="auto" title="'.$row3["name"] .' "href="profile.php?category_id='.$uid4 .'">' .$blabber_pic2. '</a><br />
          </td>
          <td  width="93%" bgcolor="#EFEFEF"><a href="profile.php?id='.$uid4.'">' . $ufirstname2 . ' </a> &bull; <span style="font-size:10px; font-weight:bold; color:#A6A6A6;">' . $message_date3 . '</span><br /><p id="submessage">' . $the_message3 . '</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>';



<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".commentForm").hide();
  $(".comment").bind('click', function(){
      $(this).nextAll(".commentForm:first").slideToggle();
     return false;
});
var html = $("#text1").html();
   $(".blabinput").click(function() {
console.log("AJAX EVENT OCCURED") 
       $.post($('#comment').attr("action"),
              $("#comment").serialize(),

        function(html) {
                      // Find the first table after the form in the HTML from the server and append it to the form on the page.

                      $(html) .find('form + table').insertAfter('#comment').after('<br />');

       });
       });
var html2 = $("#text2").html();
   $(".bringinput").click(function() {
console.log("AJAX EVENT OCCURED") 
       $.post($('#bring').attr("action"),
              $("#bring").serialize(),

        function(html2) {
                      // Find the first table after the form in the HTML from the server and append it to the form on the page.

                      $(html2) .find('form + table').insertAfter('#bring').after('<br />');

       });
       });
    });
```

That's what I have so far. the first form the parent form is submitting and posting with the jquery of id #message, then the #bring id for the id of the second form or the response form is not working properly, it is inserting but posting the comment in the p tags with id only., that's where the parent comment post not the response comment form. it should post below but, somehow I have the html and the jquery mess up. Need help in there.

the comment text is sliding toggling but the second time I click on, meaning sometimes it won't toggle the first time I click on it. But the main issue now is getting the responses form displaying below and Ajaxing without browser refresh.

Comment: It might help if you post your PHP also. The first problem I see: you have the same id for two elements: <p id="only">...

Comment: luke you are in the right direction I think I should create a counter to generate a different id for p everytime a comment post. But now with a differnet id in each comment how can I use that then ?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to modify the database table that holds your comments to add a "parent" column. A top-level comment will have a parent ID of 0, meaning it is not a response to any other comment.

Responses will have the ID of the top-level comment in their parent column.

After modifying your table, you will need to modify your PHP code to recognize responses to top-level comments, and modify your HTML to display them appropriately.

Comment: i will come with some modification later on

Comment: what I done is to greate an foreign key for nested comments instead of your approach, but I will create a parent colunm for the comment. for the responses I have a commented_mem_id field which is int of 11.

Comment: I have edited on top, with the php part for now then the html will come later.if you don't mind let's take a look at the php.

Comment: George Cummins any suggestions?